# Generating a random date with exceptions in R

Tags: r, date

I want to create a random date variable given the time frame with exceptions in R. I was able to generate a random date:

```
random_date = sample(x = seq(from = as.Date("2022-01-01"),
                             to   = as.Date("2022-12-31"),
                             by   = 'day'),
                     size = 1)
```

Now, I want to filter the random date with exception dates:

```
exception_date = c(as.Date("2022-04-01"), as.Date("2022-08-01"), as.Date("2022-12-01"))
```

Is it possible to filter these given dates using the `seq` function, or should I use a different approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not filter in the `seq()`-function, but you can use `setdiff()` to exclude the exception dates in the `sample()`function. The only problem is that `setdiff()` transforms the result into `numeric` and you have to transform it back to `Date`.

```r
exception_date = c(as.Date("2022-04-01"), as.Date("2022-08-01"), as.Date("2022-12-01"))

random_date = sample(x = as.Date(setdiff(
  seq(from = as.Date("2022-01-01"), to = as.Date("2022-12-31"),by = 'day'), exception_date),
  origin="1970-01-01"), size = 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can subset your sequence using `%in%`:

```
exception_date <- c(as.Date("2022-04-01"), as.Date("2022-08-01"), as.Date("2022-12-01"))
time_seq <- seq(from = as.Date("2022-01-01"),
                to   = as.Date("2022-12-31"),
                by   = 'day')
time_seq <- time_seq[!time_seq %in% exception_date]
random_date <- sample(x = time_seq, size = 1)
```